# Передача координат метки со страницы и обновление её положения

Tags: яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

На странице есть два поля и кнопка, в поля передаются координаты текущего положения метки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при ручном вводе координат в эти поля и нажатии на кнопку передать новые координаты метки, чтобы она автоматически переместилась на них?

```
<div id="map_container">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
<input id="geomapx" type="text" name="geox" value="">
<input id="geomapy" type="text" name="geoy" value="">
<input type="button" value="Кнопка">
```

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
// Создание карты.
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    // Координаты центра карты.Порядок по умолчнию: «широта, долгота».
    center: [55.76, 37.64],
    // Уровень масштабирования. Допустимые значения: от 0 (весь мир) до 19.
    zoom: 10
}, {
    // Поисковая строка
    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
});

var value = [];
value[1] = document.getElementById("geomapx").value;
value[0] = document.getElementById("geomapy").value;
var address;
var defaultAddress = [55.6, 37.7];
if(value){
    address = value
}else {
    address = defaultAddress
};

// Создаем геообъект с типом геометрии "Точка".
myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    // Описание геометрии.
    geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: address
    },
    // Свойства.
    properties: {
        // Контент метки.
        iconContent: 'М',
        // Балун откроется при клике по метке.
        balloonContent: 'Меня можно перемещать'
    },
}, {
    // Иконка метки будет растягиваться под размер ее содержимого.
    preset: 'twirl#redStretchyIcon',
    // Метку можно перемещать.
    draggable: true
});


myGeoObject.events.add("dragend", function (e) {
    var coords = e.get('target').geometry.getCoordinates();
    document.getElementById('geomapy').value = coords[0].toPrecision(6);
    document.getElementById('geomapx').value = coords[1].toPrecision(6);
});

myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);
```

}

Comment: `myGeoObject.setCoordinates(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отслеживайте нажатие кнопки и применяйте значения Number() полей к геообъекту через `myGeoObject.geometry.setCoordinates(address)`

Метод мониторинга вы можете выбрать самостоятельно. Рабочий пример на фиддле:
https://jsfiddle.net/Coroner1st/uq9m5cyx/